# Airtable returns not all records via API

Tags: airtable

I do load aittable records via their API:

```js
  const base = airtable.base(item.baseId);

  base("Dishes")
    .select({
    })
    .eachPage(
      function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
        tableRecords.push(...records);

        // To fetch the next page of records, call `fetchNextPage`.
        // If there are more records, `page` will get called again.
        // If there are no more records, `done` will get called.
        fetchNextPage();
      },
      function done(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log("@@Done", tableRecords.length);
      }
    );
```

and as a result, I receive 2202 records. But in the table in UI I do see 2271 records. And when I do export to csv - I see the same 2271 as well.

Code is pretty basic, I even remove `view` setting to ensure, that it's not a presentational issue.

Google did not help me (nothing related). Did anyone face the same issue? Any solution?

NB: for sure I already compared both lists and found items I do miss, but while observing those items I see nothing special there. So it says me `what` I do miss, but not `why`

Comment: have you tried `.all()`? https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js/releases/tag/v0.5.0

Comment: https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js/issues/285

Answer (score 0):

```js
const base = airtable.base(item.baseId);

base("Dishes")
  .select({})
  .all()
```

Comment: ```
(node:21094) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined
    at /Users/vvscode/repo/airtableExport/node_modules/airtable/src/query.ts:162:28
    at /Users/vvscode/repo/airtableExport/node_modules/airtable/src/run_action.ts:90:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Comment: even if I add check in those lines - I do receive null on the output

Comment: reported about it at https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js/issues/285

Comment: looks like this issue popped up earlier this year: https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js/issues/246 <- scroll to the very end!

Comment: so it recommends to switch back to eachPage , which I initially have